# How to Detect Internet Connectivity in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xam.Connectivity plugin for checking Internet Connectivity.
Here is my code

```cs
if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
{
    DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().ShowSnackBar("No Internet Connection");
}
```

If I need to check internet every second then I am calling this code every second using Device Timer.This code is good,but I want to detect when Internet goes down with out using any Timer.

So how to achieve this?

Comment: Use a ConnectivityChangedEventHandler : https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/ConnectivityPlugin/ConnectivityChanges.html You can also change to Xamarin.Essentials and use the ConnectivityChanged handler : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off to use the event that is implemented for this.

```
CrossConnectivity.Current.ConnectivityChanged += async (sender, args) =>
{
    if (!args.IsConnected)
         DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().ShowSnackBar("No Internet Connection");
};
```

Whenever the connection state now changes, you will be notified automatically.

Please note that you are using the "old" plugin. This functionality is now also captured in the [Xamarin.Essentials library](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials) which works similar, but will probably be the maintained version from now.